# Remove duplicates from multiple columns IF timeperiod is under condition

Tags: r, duplicates, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe containing 12 columns, a small preview of the data looks like this:

```
Unique1                Unique2        Unique3    DateTimeOld         Device1    Device2   Device3            MobileTablet   Desktop            DateTime            Date       Time
1 da-DK;da;q=0.8;en-US 4131620418     615        2015-06-01 00:06:06 mobile web android   computer            1             0                  2015-06-01 00:06:00 2015-06-01 00:06:00
2 da-DK;da;q=0.8;en-US 4131620418     615        2015-06-01 00:06:38 mobile web android   computer            1             0                  2015-06-01 00:06:00 2015-06-01 00:06:00
3                   da        537     747        2015-06-01 00:13:23        web                               0             1                  2015-06-01 00:13:00 2015-06-01 00:13:00
4                   da        537     747        2015-06-01 00:14:12        web                               0             1                  2015-06-01 00:14:00 2015-06-01 00:14:00
5                   da        537     747        2015-06-01 00:14:47        web                               0             1                  2015-06-01 00:14:00 2015-06-01 00:14:00
6                   da        537     747        2015-06-01 00:15:13        web                               0             1                  2015-06-01 00:15:00 2015-06-01 00:15:00
```

The data contains a lot of various users visiting a website. The first 3 columns is used to identify the user, where every user has his/her own unique combination. 
I want to remove all the duplicates of the data IF the time difference between the next user interaction is less than 30 minutes from the previous interaction.

Meaning that if a unique user "A", has visited the site at 00:14, and then visits the site again at 00:15, then this row should be deleted as 00:15-00:14=00:01<00:30.

If another unique user "B" has visited the site at 00:07, and then again at 00:40, then this row should NOT be deleted as 00:40-00:07 is NOT less than 00:30 
If a third user "C" visited the site at 00:13, and then again at 00:30 and then at 00:50, then the two other rows should be deleted because 00:30-00:13=00:17<00:30 and 00:50-00:30=00:20<00:30

The problem I have is that the Unique users can be intertwined, so a simple function of the previous row minus the next row to calculate time is not an option as I see it.

Answer (score 0):

Split the data by your users so you can run a simple function on each group. lapply/split and by are other options, but I used tapply:

```
x$timesincelastvisit <- unlist(tapply(x$DateTimeOld,INDEX = paste(x$Unique1,x$Unique2,x$Unique3),function(x){
  c(NA,diff(sort(x)))
}))
x[x$timesincelastvisit > 30 | is.na(x$timesincelastvisit), ]
```

Diff() might calculate seconds like mine did using your example data, so you would have to change "> 30" to "> 30*60"